# MySQL Select Function

Tags: php, mysql

I have three fields in my table called `data`. The fields are called timestamp, locationID and event. The below mySQL query is intended to take the data from the table and create four columns: `timestamp`, `movement`, `peoplein` and `peopleout`.

When I run the query, I get the following message: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). There definitely is data in the table so I'm wondering if someone could help me spot the issue with the code below.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME( FLOOR( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( TIMESTAMP ) / 600 ) *600 ) AS `timekey`, 
SUM( event ) AS `movement`, 
SUM( IF( event > 0, event, 0 ) ) AS `peoplein`, 
SUM( IF( event < 0, ABS( event ) , 0 ) ) AS `peopleout`
FROM `data`
WHERE DATE( TIMESTAMP ) = DATE( NOW( ) ) 
GROUP BY `timekey`
ORDER BY `timekey` ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression:

```
WHERE TIMESTAMP = DATE( NOW( ) )
```

would fail because `Timestamp` has a time component.  Although using `date` fixes it, it is recommended to do:

```
where timestamp >= curdate() and
      timestamp < date_add(curdate(), interval 1 day)
```

This version allows your query to take advantage of an index on `timestamp`.

Comment: Gordon, it doesn't *fail* as you seem to suggest, so you may want to clean up that bit. It may not be as efficient as your proposed query but it definitely *works* and the use of `date()` will in no way cause the "empty result set" issue.  You can see that if you just enter `create table x(y timestamp); insert into x values (now()); select * from x where date(y) = date(now());` into MySQL.

Comment: @paxdiablo . . . That is really strange, I didn't notice the `DATE()` in the original query (I thought that was the problem).  I changed the wording.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE DATE( TIMESTAMP ) = DATE( NOW( ) )
```

There may *well* be data in the table but, unless there's data in the table for *today,* you're not going to see anything.

In terms of debugging SQL generally, it's often a good idea to strip things away until it starts to deliver some results (or start from a minimum and add things until it doesn't). The last thing removed/added will then be the likely culprit and you can narrow your focus to that.

Comment: For debugging, I would also suggest downloading mysql workbench to test your queries. Or any sql management tool for each different platform.